# Google Cloud Print downloadable?

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have a problem with Google Cloud Print. It works perfectly, but it's a bit annoying that every time I have to upload the file on the web. I searched for a long time for a program that could use Google Cloud Print printers as a normal printer where I could press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and it just worked, but I didn't find anything, so I would like to ask you if any of you ever heard about such a program?

Comment: how to take print? i did sign in to Google Cloud printer with my account.., but my printer which is connected to my PC is not showing in the list.. did i miss anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paperless Printer is a Windows virtual printer that allows you to print from a desktop application and have the print job sent to a remote Google cloud enabled printer. This product 
a 100% free for non-commercial use.

http://rarefind.com/paperlessprinter/index.html

Paperless Printer can also publish documents in PDF, TIFF, PNG, JPEG, etc,.

Cheers,
Ajay